# How to properly typeset numbers with multiple fonts?

Tags: fonts, typography, math-fonts

In my documents, I use different fonts: one for the text, another for the math. Is there a rule to know for writing numbers? There are some examples:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? Also, an MWE would probably help.

Comment: This is a typography question, not a technical one. How to prefer type `$5$` instead of `5` in a text, where there is a different font for the main text and the math environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aesthetics are bit strange for me personally when the running line is in serif, and the numbers are in sans. The other way around seems fine, especially for math. I guess as long as you are consistent, you can do anything. But I should let the math people answer, because I know nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two packages with commands to change the font of numbers in math mode specifically: `unicode-math` (which requires LuaTeX or XeTeX), and `mathspec` (which requires XeTeX).  In addition, you can use `mathastext` for the most common use case: using the text font for letters and numbers in math mode, so `$1$` looks like `1`.

For most documents, the best way to achieve this is to load matching text and math font packages, or set compatible fonts with `\setmainfont` and `\setmathfont`.

With `unicode-math`, you would use a command like `\setmathfont[range={up/num}, Scale=MatchUppercase]` to change the font of only the digits.  For `mathspec`, you would use `\setmathsfont(Digits)`.

In PDFTeX, you might need to create a `digits` math alphabet with `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and insert ten commands like

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`0}
```